# Export data in file in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, psql

I have one table with id, name and complex queries. Below is just a sample of that table..

```
ID  name          Query
1   advisor_1     "Select * from advisor"
2   student_1     "Select * from student where id = 12"
3   faculty_4     "Select * from student where id = 12"
```

I want to iterate over this table and save each record into the csv file

Is there any way I can do it though Anonymous block automatically.
I don't want to do this manually as table has lots of rows.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: COPY TO with csv in dynamic SQL would work in a DO block but you need to be superuser for the permission to write into server-side files.

Comment: @DanielVérité I tried that .. but I dont have super user permission.. Is there any other way?

Comment: Without superuser you can only copy to standard output, but you can't do it from a anonymous block. However it's relatively easy to do in any programming language, just iterate over results of your table and then issuing COPY for each one. Take a look on [this example](https://gist.github.com/michelmilezzi/e35cc4ad257893043fc9bff1b91c3c0f) using java.

Comment: Can I use \copy command in anonymous block? Or Can I iterate over in psql?

Comment: You definitely should to specify the set of tools you can use. BTW look at [`\gexec` metacommand](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) (introduced since 9.6 version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not being superuser means the export can't be done in a server-side DO block.

It could be done client-side in any programming language that can talk to the database, or assuming a psql-only environment, it's possible to generate a list of `\copy` statements with an SQL query.

As an example of the latter, assuming the unique output filenames are built from the `ID` column, something like this should work:

```
SELECT format('\copy (%s) TO ''file-%s.csv'' CSV', query, id)
 FROM table_with_queries;
```

The result of this query should be put into a file in a format such that it  can be directly included into psql, like this:

```
\pset format unaligned
\pset tuples_only on

-- \g with an argument treats it as an output file.
SELECT format('\copy (%s) TO ''file-%s.csv'' CSV', query, id)
 FROM table_with_queries \g /tmp/commands.sql

\i /tmp/commands.sql
```

As a sidenote, that process cannot be managed with the `\gexec` meta-command introduced in PG 9.6, because `\copy` itself is a meta-command. `\gexec` iterates only on SQL queries, not on meta-commands. Otherwise the whole thing could be done by a single `\gexec` invocation.

Comment: Will it generate file for each of the row?

Comment: @MadhuraMhatre: yes. It assumes that you expect a different output file for each query.

Comment: not for each query I want for each row from that query

Answer (score 0):

You may use a function like: (**IF** your problem is the code)

```
DECLARE
    rec RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR rec IN SELECT id, query FROM table_name
    LOOP 
        EXECUTE('COPY (' || rec.query || ') TO ' || QUOTE_LITERAL('d:/csv' || rec.id || '.csv') || ' CSV'); 
    END LOOP;
END;
```

for permission problem, You should use some places on server that you have writing access to them (or request from vendor).

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have superuser permissions. 
Can I use \copy command in anonymous block? Or Can I iterate over in psql?